# how to display a default option in a dropdown list

Tags: java, html, struts

Given

```html
<html:select property="loginPathId" style="width:190px">
    <option value=""></option>
    <html:optionsCollection property="loginPath" value="id" label="displayName"/>
</html:select>
```

Right now, it is a dropdown list with an empty default value. how do i populate it by default with say `option value=1`?

Can this be done **without** using jQuery, and only with struts, java, javascript and html?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside the option you wanted selected:

```
<option selected="selected">value</option>
```

Comment: so we hard code the value? is there any way to retrieve it from optionscollections?

Comment: not sure...I know to programatically set it you can use jQuery and the .attr() function.

Comment: Made a quick fiddle of programatically setting the default: http://jsfiddle.net/Kpm83/

Answer (score 0):

```
<html:select property="status" value="...your status choise here...">
  <html:optionsCollection name="loginPath" label="displayName" value="id" />
</html:select>
```

Comment: can you give a quick example please?

Comment: @bouncingHippo check i updated my code put value attribute and then specify the your value

Comment: Setting a value in the action class with getter/setter is meaningless in Struts 1. The corresponding ActionForm property needs to be set, or you can put the value into the request and access it via EL, etc.

Comment: that  is previous answer .I forgot to delete it